# Safari Browser ignoring zIndex

Tags: css

I have a small problem on a web page (http://goldschmiede-h-j-baier.de/dev/index.php?id=10) everything is displayed correctly, the footer is pushed upwards with z-index. but safari does the z-index does not and I do not know why. the footer is always placed behind the main container ...

```
/*Website*/
html,body {
  background:#000;
  font-family:"Trebuchet MS",Helvetica,Jamrul,sans-serif;
  color:#fff;
  overflow:hidden;
  border-left: 5px solid;
  border-right: 5px solid;
}
.maincontainer {
  overflow:auto;
  height:100%;
  width: 100%;
}
#footer {
  height:64px;
  position:fixed;
  bottom:30px;
  z-index:200;
}
#navigation {
  position:fixed;
  left:30%;
}

#logo {
  background:url(../images/logo-baier.png);
  width:217px;
  height:75px;
  position:fixed;
  bottom:30px;
  z-index:202;
  left:10%;
}
#social {
  position:fixed;
  right:0;
  top:30px;
  z-index:302;
}



/*Slider*/
#slides {
  position:relative;
}
.slides {
  background:#000;
  /*margin-top:10px;*/
  border-bottom: 10px solid #fff;
   border-top: 10px solid #fff;
}
#slides .slides-container {
  display:none;
}
#slides .scrollable {
  *zoom:1;
  position:relative;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  overflow-y:auto;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch;
  height:100%;
}
#slides .scrollable:after {
  content:"";
  display:table;
  clear:both;
}
.slides-navigation {
  margin:0 auto;
  position:absolute;
  z-index:3;
  top:56%;
  width:100%;
}
.slides-navigation a {
  position:absolute;
  display:block;
}
.slides-navigation a.prev {
  left:0px;
}
.slides-navigation a.next {
  right:0px;
}
.slides-pagination {
  position:absolute;
  z-index:3;
  bottom:0;
  text-align:center;
  width:100%;
}
.slides-pagination a {
  border:2px solid #222;
  border-radius:15px;
  width:10px;
  height:10px;
  display:-moz-inline-stack;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
  *vertical-align:auto;
  zoom:1;
  *display:inline;
  background-image:url("data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAQAAAC1HAwCAAAAC0lEQVR4nGP6zwAAAgcBApocMXEAAAAASUVORK5CYII=");
  margin:2px;
  overflow:hidden;
  text-indent:-100%;
}
.slides-pagination a.current {
  background:#222;
}
.next {
  width:35px;
  height:55px;
  background-image:url("../images/str.png");
  background-position:42px -44px;
}
.prev {
  width:35px;
  height:55px;
  background-image:url("../images/str.png");
  background-position:-7px -44px;
}
.slides-pagination {
  display:none;
}
.bottom {
  position:absolute;
  z-index:3000;
  bottom:90px;
  width:100%;
  right:-60%;
}
.bottom a {
  width:51px;
  height:32px;
  background-image:url("../images/str.png");
  background-position:0px 0px;
  display:inline-block;
}
.top {
  position:absolute;
  z-index:3000;
  top:0;
  text-align:center;
  width:100%;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.top a {
  width:51px;
  height:32px;
  background-image:url("../images/str.png");
  background-position:-68px 0px;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: place the markup what you have applied rather than showing website.

Comment: Suggestion: Try to create a separate simplistic demo removing all the unnecessary HTML markup and CSS, than do the test. The issue will pop out by it self, rather than struggling with all that lines of CSS that has nothing to do with the real problem

Comment: the problem was a jqueryscript